# Preprocessing for easier parsing in ANTLR

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, antlr4, language-design

I am trying to make a language with a very minimalist naturalistic syntax. Essentially, a declaration followed by lines of marked up normal text.

```
@decleration
The first line that is just normal text #someMetaData
The second line <markup> with more normal text

@decleration2
<moreMarkup> more normal text #MoreMetaData
```

This was a huge pain to get working in ANTLR though, so I changed it to this "explicit" syntax instead:

```
@decleration
~"The first line that is just normal text" #someMetaData
~"The second line "<markup>" with more normal text"

@decleration2
~<moreMarkup>" more normal text" #MoreMetaData
```

This syntax is very easy to parse, but ultimately isn't what I want for the language.

My question is this: is there some straightforward/elegant way to take the first syntax, do a bit of preprocessing, and spit out the second syntax, within ANTLR4? It might not be too hard to write a preprocessor manually, but I'd rather avoid two-levels of parsing if I can.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're going to use Antlr, there's probably a lot to be said for [reading the book](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/), but if you don't want to shell out for a copy of the whole thing, the section on [Island Parsing](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/islands.pdf), which is basically what you're trying to do here, is available from the publisher's site as a promo excerpt.

Comment: ANLTR seems a little over-killed for your syntax. As you are using C#, you could have a look at some parser combinator libraries: https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/Pidgin, https://github.com/sebastienros/parlot

Comment: That looks very much like the Markup language. You may want to use that instead of rolling yet another similar language?